# Keydown event is not working properly

Tags: jquery

My requirement is to uncheck the checkbox if the textbox value is greater than 0. But it is unchecking after two key downs.          I cant identify the error... Please someone help me.

```
     $('#'+QID+' TABLE TBODY TR').find("input[type='text']").live('keydown',function()
      {
       if($(this).val().length > 0)
       {
            $('#'+ExQID+' TABLE TBODY TR').siblings('TR').find(':checkbox').prop('checked',false)
       }
      });
```

Comment: I think this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581946/how-to-restore-textbox-data

Comment: @ApoY2k: 56% is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text box text capture using Jquery always 'one character behind'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676435/text-box-text-capture-using-jquery-always-one-character-behind)

Comment: Have you thought about what will happen if the user enters a value into the textbox via some medium other than a key press? What if the user right clicks and pastes some text in? Or if the user clicks on an autocomplete suggestion? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314240/detecting-autocomplete-on-form-input-with-jquery/3314247#3314247) discusses these issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keydown` fires before the value changes in the DOM.

So:

- the first time the event fires, you're inserting the first character into the textbox *but the DOM doesn't know this yet*, so `$(this).val().length` is still 0;
- the second time the event fires, you're inserting the second character into the textbox, and `$(this).val().length` is 1 from the last time.

Instead, use the `keyup` event, which fires after the textbox value is updated.

Answer (score 0):

use keyup insted of keydown

```
 $('#'+QID+' TABLE TBODY TR').find("input[type='text']").live('keyup',function()
      {
       if($(this).val().length > 0)
       {
            $('#'+ExQID+' TABLE TBODY TR').siblings('TR').find(':checkbox').prop('checked',false)
       }
      });
```